# Is there a way to output the machine name of a taxonomy term?

Tags: theming

I've been to figure out how I can output the machine-name of a taxonomy term on my entity field to my twig template. using `.label` prints out the name of the taxonomy term. `.id` get a numerical value, was actually hoping to get the machine term instead. Using `kint` I can't seem to find it

```
{% for themes in node.field_themes %}

        <span>{{ themes.entity.id }}</span>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: You can try this one {{ themes.entity.name|lower|replace({' ': '-'}) }}

Comment: using `.entity.id` output a numerical value

Comment: @AlexKuzava the correct way is `{{ themes.entity.label|lower|replace({' ':'-'}) }}` but thanks for the hint. Kindly submit this as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I see, the output I'm looking for somewhat like the key value of a
>   list field. For example *Taxonomy term* it becomes *taxonomy-term*

As discussed the correct way is

```
{{ themes.entity.label|lower|replace({' ':'-'}) }}
```

It's suitable for other entity types as well

Answer (score 3):

I found this to work in the taxonomy term individual twig template: taxonomy-term.html.twig :

```
{% set term_machine_name = term.name.value|raw|lower|replace({' ':'-'})|replace({',':'-'}) %}
```

Then use `term_machine_name` as required.

If you are outputting the *Taxonomy term: Name* field in a View, I found this to work, in the rewrite results setting in the Views Display Config, when editing a View in the site's admin pages:

```
<a href="#{{ name |lower|replace({' ':'-'})|replace({',':'-'}) }}">{{ name__value }}</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Taxonomy terms are content entities, and don’t have machine names.

They have IDs, that’s how they’re generally identified.

Comment: I see, the output I'm looking for somewhat like the key value of a list field. For example `Taxonomy term` it becomes `taxonomy-term`

Comment: You probably need to use php to achieve that. Preprocess the theme and use `preg_replace` or something.